# Import-Csv - Member already present issue

Tags: powershell, csv

I have to combine multiple CSV files into a single one. Each of the CSV has a header. One of the columns header is identical. Ideally, the end file (all_out.csv) has to have a single header.

I run the PowerShell code:

```
Import-Csv out_1_result.csv,out_2_result.csv,out_3_result.csv,out_4_result.csv,out_5_result.csv,out_6_result.csv,out_7_result.csv,out_8_result.csv,out_9_result.csv,out_10_result.csv,out_11_result.csv,out_12_result.csv,out_13_result.csv,out_14_result.csv,out_15_result.csv,out_16_result.csv,out_17_result.csv,out_18_result.csv,out_19_result.csv,out_20_result.csv,out_21_result.csv,out_22_result.csv,out_23_result.csv,out_24_result.csv,out_25_result.csv,out_26_result.csv,out_27_result.csv,out_28_result.csv |
    Export-Csv all_out.csv -NoType
```

and I end up with an error

> Import-Csv : The member "URL" is already present.

Is there a way to ignore/fix this?

Comment: At least one of your CSVs has a duplicate column "URL". PowerShell doesn't support that. Remove the duplicate column from the input file(s) to fix the issue.

Comment: Do these CSV's actually have the same header or any headers at all?

Answer (score 14):

> One of the columns header is identical

That means each CSV has two columns header 'URL'?  `Import-Csv` creates objects where each header becomes a property name, e.g. `@{Id=10; Url='example.com'}`  and using the same name again will clash.

There is no way this will work cleanly without you changing the csv files, as there is no way to say "use different column names" and also "skip the header row" just with the Import-Csv cmdlet.

The easiest change I can think of is to drop the header line from each one, e.g.:

```
$CsvFiles = 'out_1_result.csv','out_2_result.csv','out_3_result.csv','out_4_result.csv','out_5_result.csv','out_6_result.csv','out_7_result.csv','out_8_result.csv','out_9_result.csv','out_10_result.csv','out_11_result.csv','out_12_result.csv','out_13_result.csv','out_14_result.csv','out_15_result.csv','out_16_result.csv','out_17_result.csv','out_18_result.csv','out_19_result.csv','out_20_result.csv','out_21_result.csv','out_22_result.csv','out_23_result.csv','out_24_result.csv','out_25_result.csv','out_26_result.csv','out_27_result.csv','out_28_result.csv'

$NewFileNames = $CsvFiles | ForEach-Object { 

    $NewFileName = $_ + "_noheader.csv"

    Get-Content $_ | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content $NewFileName -Encoding UTF8

    $NewFileName   # write new name to output stream

}
```

And then, when they have no header line, import them all and specify the header line as a parameter

```
Import-Csv -Path $NewFileNames -Header 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Url1', 'Url2' | Export-Csv ...
```

Comment: I would think that you could just read in each file use `GC | select -skip 1 | convertfrom-csv` that would skip the need for temp files. use case will vary obviously.

Comment: Is there a reason you set the `-Encoding UTF8`?

Comment: @Matt yes that looks workable too. and, because having unicode content and not specifying an encoding = corrupt data. Having ASCII data and specifying UTF8 = works fine. Erring on the side of specifying it to make it more likely to work. Compare `[pscustomobject]@{'x'='↮'} | epcsv x; gc x` with `[pscustomobject]@{'x'='↮'} | epcsv x -encoding utf8; gc x` in PowerShell ISE

Comment: This can also happen if you have a # sign at the beginning of your header line.

Answer (score 0):

Place `-Encoding` parameter at the end of the command

```
Import-Csv -Path $output -Encoding UTF8

Export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $output -Encoding UTF8
```